# crashLytics - Real time log exception

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am using Crashlytics in my android app. In one especial case I handle one exception as non fatal exception. so I used `CrashlyticsCore.getInstance().logException(e);` and `CrashlyticsCore.getInstance().log("");` and it is work fine but it has one little problem . it is not real time . I mean it needs to relaunch the app . how can I see logs message in the exact time?